# How to you get a flickable to do a smooth scroll?

Tags: application-development, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

```
Flickable{
Button{
onClicked: parent.?????????
}
```

Or do I have to create a function for this?

Comment: Does this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IrMJ5W3WL8?

Comment: @TuKsn Nope; this does not tell me how to make a flickable scroll smoothly on a button press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a Flickable scroll to a specific point by setting the **contentY** property of a Flickable. Quoting the official documentation from qt-project.org,

> ContentY holds the surface coordinate currently at the top-left corner
>   of the Flickable. For example, if you flick an image up 100 pixels,
>   contentY will be 100.

So if you want to scroll a Flickable smoothly with the press of a button, you could animate the contentY property change like,

```
Behavior on contentY {
    UbuntuNumberAnimation {}
}
```

This will gradually change the value of contentY instead of setting it to its final value abruptly.

You can find more about the contentY property [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentY-prop).